# Block selecting text or selecting multiple text at once

Tags: visual-studio, text-editor

Does Visual Studio (any version) offer the ability to select text in either a block or select several snippets at once, to either change or delete?  To be clear I'm referring to the actual text-editor interface.

Comment: See my other answer for simultaneous multi-edits: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19532887/244353

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can certainly do block selection by hold down the Alt key while doing a selection

Comment: I *think* the OP is asking for multiple selections (e.g., multiple blocks or multiple "normal" selections).  But I might be wrong.

Comment: @Mark I was asking about both, actually.  BTW...what is an OP? Hopefully not an insult.

Comment: Block selection exists in VS2010. http://scottcate.com/tricks/503/ For more advanced scenarios (making changes to multiple independent selections) check out VsVim or ViEmu

Comment: @Doug, As Robert pointed out, I meant it as "original poster".  I think have seen it used to mean "original post".  And I puzzled over that acronym for a while too.

Answer (score 1):

Go to opening or closing brace and press Ctrl+Shift+].