# Multiple select in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, selection, text-editor, multi-select

Is there a way to select multiple non-adjoining (totally separate) texts in VS? I can do it in MS Word by selecting the texts separately by holding the Ctrl button, like this:

[image]

My version is 11.

**Edit:** I'm not talking about `Alt+Select` block selection. Also I would love to see if there exist a technique in Notepad++.

Comment: Are you asking about Visual Studio 2012 or Notepad++?

Comment: @Oded I thought it was obvious the question is about VS (included in the title as well). The thing about Notepad++ was a bonus question.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible in either.

Comment: For Notepad++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453151/notepad-multi-editing

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the selection, you may be able to achieve the end result with a regex/string search.

Answer (score 309, accepted):

Multi cursor edit is natively supported in Visual Studio starting from version 2017 Update 8. The following is an extract of [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-replacing-text#multi-caret-selection):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click : Add a secondary caret
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + double-click : Add a secondary word selection
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click + drag : Add a secondary selection
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> : Add the next matching text as a selection
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> : Add all matching text as selections
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> : Remove last selected occurrence
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> : Skip next matching occurrence
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click : Add a box selection
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> or click : Clear all selections

Some of those commands are also available in the `Edit` menu:

[image: Multiple Carets Menu]

Comment: I don't see these options using 2017 ver 15.9.3

Comment: Seems that in 15.9.3 the commands in the menu are just the first two.

Comment: I wonder if they are ever going to make *proper* multi-caret support like JetBrains already has for years. Try to make a couple of carets, select a word, and then copy-paste it. VS pastes double (i.e. it pastes the entire selection done with both carets per each caret. I can't imagine when this would ever be a desirable behavior. They should paste it just once. Also, JetBrains has the CTRL+CTRL shortcut, which enables adding carets when pressing the down or up arrows (indefinitely, while CTRL is pressed). It's just so much more productive than VS' implementation at this point.

Comment: @obe or like sublime. The way it is currently supported is of no use to me.

Comment: The default keyboard shortcut is `Ctrl+Alt+Select`

Comment: for mac users it's Cmd+D (https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf)

Comment: What's the difference between `Shift+Alt+Down` and `Shift+Alt+.` commands? Both seemingly create multiple carets, but the former disappears when I try to move them, and the latter persists.

Comment: I think the combinations are too short, they should require us to press 5 keys simultaneously to do basic mundane tasks.

Comment: You might need to reset your keyboard shorts back to default btw in case this isn't working for you.

Answer (score 75):

There is a new extension for Visual Studio 2017 called *SelectNextOccurrence* which is free and open-source.

[image]

> This extension makes it possible to select next occurrences of a selected text for editing.
>
> Aims to replicate the Ctrl+D command of Sublime Text for faster coding.

Features:

- Select next occurrence of current selection.
- Skip occurrence
- Undo occurrence
- Add caret above/below
- Use multiple carets to edit (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-click to add caret)

Visual Studio commands:

- `SelectNextOccurrence.SelectNextOccurrence` is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> by default.
- `SelectNextOccurrence.SkipOccurrence` is not bound by default. (Recommended <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
- `SelectNextOccurrence.UndoOccurrence` is not bound by default. (Recommended <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)
- `SelectNextOccurrence.AddCaretAbove` is not bound by default. (Recommended <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>)
- `SelectNextOccurrence.AddCaretBelow` is not bound by default. (Recommended <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>)

[image: SelectNextOccurrence options]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thomaswelen.SelectNextOccurrence

https://github.com/2mas/SelectNextOccurrence

Comment: Perfect! This is the one. Multi selection and caret work very well. Tested with VS Community 2017.

Comment: @Dave yes this extension is great. Consider giving it a good review and/or starring the GitHub project if you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you for finding this extension! MixEdit was working but it wasn't optimized for VS2017 and that trialware popup was anti-productive.

Comment: Didn't work for me. welp, I don't know what I was expecting from ms.

Comment: Great solution, just to note I also had to remove the default key bindings from `Edit.Duplicate` as they were still being honored even when adding `Ctrl+D` to the keybinding for `SelectNextOccurrence`. VS 2019 Default Shortcuts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 58):

In the Visual Studio `Shift+Alt+. / Shift+Alt+,`

- `Shift+Alt+.` - match caret;
- `Shift+Alt+,` - remove previous caret;

Same function as on VSCode `Ctrl+D`.

Much more setting `Tool - Options - Environment - keyboard`. Next in the `Show commands containing` enter `Edit.`.

Also, can use keyboard schema `Visual Studio Code`. Available for Visual Studio 2017

For conclusion, nice link [Visual Studio All keyboard shortcuts](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer kind internet user.

Comment: great answer. We just needed the commands. I dn why everyone gave such long answers, lol. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the hint to just switch to the VS Code mappings.... CTRL+D is one of my most used shortcuts in VS Code, happy to use it in VS

Answer (score 34):

In Visual Studio 2019, you can put your caret on the right place and then press SHIFT ALT and . (dot).
This will select the next occurrence.

Comment: `Shift + Alt + .`

Comment: The name of the command is `Edit.InsertNextMatchingCaret`. In case anyone want to find and bind it to a different key comb

Answer (score 23):

[MixEdit](http://www.codinglabs.net/MixEdit.aspx) extension for Visual Studio allows you to do multiediting in the way you are describing. It supports multiple carets and multiple selections.

Comment: If you're seeking something like Sublime text, this is it!

Comment: In case somebody is wondering, the way to achieve multi-selection in MixEdit is by double clicking on words after pressing `Alt`. The same as in MS Word, except it is `Alt` here instead of `Ctrl`. MixEdit also has a lot of other useful multi-select options. Bear in mind it's free only for evaluation!

Comment: I can't purchase a MixEdit license anymore. Check the [website](http://www.codinglabs.net/BuyMixEdit.aspx). Any idea how I can license it somehow and get rid of the annoying popup?

Comment: this extension is not free!!

Comment: it's great but not free and popping up annoying dialog every few times you use it. that dialog can't even be cancelled with escape so have to use mouse which is painful. paying for it is now "suspended" so can't really use it

Comment: are there any alternatives that are free or with ability to buy so you don't have to get that annoying alert ? or ability to remove it from MixEdit if there is no way to buy

Comment: Check out [this free alternative to MixEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48185483/24874) that was released recently, and is open source.

Comment: Visual studio 2017 says:
---------------------------
This extension is not compatible with Visual Studio 2017. Installation may cause Visual Studio to be unstable.  Do you want to continue?
---------------------------

Comment: No longer available, author took down the page on the VS marketplace.

Comment: [Select Next Occurrence works](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thomaswelen.SelectNextOccurrence) and is open source.

Answer (score 20):

From Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.8, **Ctrl + Alt + Click** is now supposed to be a built-in way to manage multiple carets.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/08/30/improving-your-productivity-in-the-visual-studio-editor/

Answer (score 8):

Just to note,

MixEdit is not *completely* free.

> "This software is currently not licensed to any user and is running in
>   evaluation mode. MIXEDIT may be downloaded and evaluated for free,
>   however a license must be purchased for continued use."

Upon installation and use, a popup redirects to [webpage](http://www.codinglabs.net/BuyMixEdit.aspx) - similar to SublimeText's unlicensed software pop-up message.

Comment: and now you can't even buy it. it just pops up the alert box asking for license

Answer (score 7):

### For Visual Studio Code

Got to this question because I was looking for a way to select multiple words with mouse click on VS Code, which should be achieved by using `alt+click`, but this keybinding wasn't working (I think it is something related to my OS, **Ubuntu**).

For anyone looking for something similar, try changing the key to `ctrl+click`.

Go to `Selection` > `Switch to Ctrl+Click for Multi Cursor`

Comment: You sure you are not talking about VS Code?

Comment: Yes, I am... Should I delete it or just title as "for vs code"? I was looking for code when I got here

Comment: no need to delete, will be useful for others. Just mention it in answer.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find anything built in, which is sad. There is this functionality in [CodeRush](http://www.skorkin.com/2012/07/the-support-of-multi-selection-for-visual-studio-by-coderush/#.UY4dJb2MwnU) though.

With Notepad++, this feature comes in built in. Just turn on multi-editing from

> Setting > Preferences > Editing > Multi-Editing Settings

But its not as intuitive as MS Word which lets you select two words by double clicking on them (after Ctrl of course).

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** [MixEdit](http://www.codinglabs.net/MixEdit.aspx) extension now provides this ability.

[MultiEdit](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2beb9705-b568-45d1-8550-751e181e3aef) extension for VS allows for something similar (doesn't support multiple selections as of this writing, just multiple carets)

Head over to Hanselman's for a quick animated gif of this in action: [Simultaneous Editing for Visual Studio with the free MultiEdit extension](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimultaneousEditingForVisualStudioWithTheFreeMultiEditExtension.aspx)

Comment: This extension doesn't support multiple selections, as requested in the original question.  The [MixEdit extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495727/multiple-select-in-visual-studio#answer-27234819) does.

Comment: MixEdit didn't exist when the OP posted his question. I answered to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

in visual 2019,  Open Options to show all
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkytK.png)

and multi select: keep `Ctrl + Alt` then click position you want
or, keep `Shift + Alt` then click position to multi select multi line from start to end line clicked

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is a available for earlier versions, but using Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition, there is the option to convert the keyboard setup to match Visual Studio Code.

Head into **Tools** > **Options** > **Environment** > **Keyboard**, then drop down the **Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme:** list and select **Visual Studio Code**.

[image: Keyboard settings - Visual Studio 2022 Community]

Note that this initialises the basic keyboard setup for VS Code, so any changes that you've made in your personal VS Code editor won't be included; you'll need to set these up yourself.

While this doesn't directly answer the OP's question, it does give a commonality between editors, and I do much prefer the VS Code keyboard setup (with tweaks) to the Visual Studio's.

Answer (score 4):

There is supposedly a way to do it now with `Ctrl + Alt + Click` but I use this extension because it has a bunch of other nice features that I use: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thomaswelen.SelectNextOccurrence

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2022, it's the `Edit.InsertNextMatchingCaret`, as you can see in this sreenshot :

[Click to see the sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mvlM.png)

I am familiar with Visual Studio Code, so I applied the `Ctrl + D`. You must choose `Text Editor`.

Answer (score 1):

For mac users using visual studio code `CMD+D` works like a charm

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Now the plugin is Multi Line tricks. The end and start buttons broke the selection.

Comment: how to install in visual studio 2015?

Answer (score -3):

For multi-select, you can use CTRL-SHIFT-L. You can click over the word and then press key combinations(CTRL-SHIFT-L) this will select all same types of words from the file(vs-code).

Comment: the question is for visual studio