# Multiple select in Visual Studio in Mac VS?

Tags: visual-studio

Same question as [Multiple select in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495727/multiple-select-in-visual-studio) except is it available for Mac? I can't seem to find the setting anywhere, or any info on it.

Is there multi-cursor/caret support on Mac VS? I'm working in a c# environment if that makes any difference?

Comment: Check [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_basic-editing). If you are on a Mac you should see the key bindings for it.

Comment: @EdgarR.Mondragón unfortunately that didn't work :( I did some more hunting and apparently it's not available natively as best I can tell.