# Reactivate Multi Caret Shortcut after Resharper in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, resharper, multi-select, caret

The usual multi caret short cut since VS2019 is

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click : Add a secondary caret

as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52015155/5174469).

After the installation of resharper it overrides this shortcut unfortunately with a navigation feature.

I looked throughout the shortcuts in environment-keyboard options in VS but apparently you cannot change or reinstate this shortcut according to [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-changing-shortcut-for-multi-editmulti-caret/451479).

How do I get my beloved multi-caret functionality back into my hands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! The Solution is to take away the key combination from Resharper.

Go to Resharper Options => Environment => Search & Navigation
and uncheck the Ctrl + Alt + Click checkbox:

[image]

and Visual Studio will allow you again to use the multi-caret functionality!

Here is the [original link](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206651485-Disable-Ctrl-Click-Navigate?page=1#community_comment_206412499) on how to disable the navigation functionality in resharper.