# Photoshop-like-selecting in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way for Photoshop-like-selecting in visual studio?

- ClickDrag to select
- Shift+ClickDrag to increase selection (maybe a couple of rows below)
- Alt-ClickDrag to decrease selection (to make a hole in the selection)

Comment: do you mean text selection? after you selected some text you can move the cursor and select more by holding shift + arrow keys. you then can use ctrl + arrow keys or pos1 or end to move the cursor faster

Comment: But then you only expand or reduce the selection, right?
I´m looking for a way to select a function i want to make a copy of, but then deselect some inner stuff that I am not interested in. So I can get the shell of something as a template

Comment: yes. is this not what you meant?

Comment: I want to make a selection with holes. ...or select every second row in some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think ctrl + alt + clickdrag is what you are looking for.

more shortcuts here in this question
[Multiple select in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495727/multiple-select-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is what i´m looking for!!